# lftp connection hanging (instead of failing)

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-networking

i have an automated script that uses lftp to connect to a server and download a file.  i've had the script run successfully quite a few times (so i know in theory it works).  recently, i suspect we are having issues connecting to the remote server (we don't own it so i can't validate whether it is "up" or "down").

i know lftp connects via ssh.  when i run the lftp program, it just constantly tries to reconnect.

```
/bin/lftp -d -e 'set sftp:connect-program "ssh -a -x -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa -o "ConnectionAttempts=1" -o "ConnectTimeout=10" -o "BatchMode=yes" -o "ServerAliveInterval=15""; set cmd:fail-exit on; set dns:max-retries 3; set dns:fatal-timeout 20; set net:max-retries 3; set net:timeout 25; set ssl:key-file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa; set xfer:clobber on; get OUT/remote_filename.txt -o remote_filename.txt; bye' -uremoteusername,xyz sftp://sftp.remoteserver.com

---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa -o ConnectionAttempts=1 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o BatchMode=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -s -l remoteusername sftp.remoteserver.com sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
<--- Connection timed out during banner exchange          
**** Peer closed connection
---- Disconnecting
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa -o ConnectionAttempts=1 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o BatchMode=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -s -l remoteusername sftp.remoteserver.com sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
<--- Connection timed out during banner exchange          
**** Peer closed connection
---- Disconnecting
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa -o ConnectionAttempts=1 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o BatchMode=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -s -l remoteusername sftp.remoteserver.com sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
<--- Connection timed out during banner exchange          
**** Peer closed connection
---- Disconnecting
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa -o ConnectionAttempts=1 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o BatchMode=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -s -l remoteusername sftp.remoteserver.com sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
<--- Connection timed out during banner exchange          
**** Peer closed connection
---- Disconnecting
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa -o ConnectionAttempts=1 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o BatchMode=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -s -l remoteusername sftp.remoteserver.com sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
<--- Connection timed out during banner exchange          
**** Peer closed connection
---- Disconnecting
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa -o ConnectionAttempts=1 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o BatchMode=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -s -l remoteusername sftp.remoteserver.com sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
<--- Connection timed out during banner exchange          
**** Peer closed connection
---- Disconnecting
Interrupt
```

you can see it tried to reconnect at least 6 times before i manually killed it.  it seems to be ignoring the max-retries of 3.

if i manually test the underlying ssh connection, that seems to be failing (after 1 try):

```
ssh -v -v -v -a -x -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa -o ConnectionAttempts=1 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o BatchMode=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -s -l remoteusername sftp.remoteserver.com sftp
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 60: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /usr/bin/sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy -p 22     sftp.remoteserver.com
debug3: timeout: 10000 ms remain after connect
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1839400042
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
Connection timed out during banner exchange
```

So, the problem looks like the initial setup in ssh.  It looks like lftp doesn't realize ssh is failing somehow, so it keeps trying to setup the connection.

Is there a way to get the two to play nicely?  I'd like to avoid my script hanging forever as it tries to make the connection.

Thanks!

Comment: a clue can be to use sftp instead of lftp